# Echo an items label in a module

Tags: module

I have used the Joomla Component Creator to make a component and a module.

Now I'm trying to modify the output of the module.

I can use

> echo ($element->my_field)

to echo the value of my field in the module.
But I cannot figure out how to echo the **field label.**

In helper.php there is a function to render headers which looks like this:

```
public static function renderTranslatableHeader(&$params, $field)
    {
        return JText::_(
            'MOD_VECKOMATSEDEL_HEADER_FIELD_' . str_replace('#__', '', strtoupper($params->get('table'))) . '_' . strtoupper($field)
        );
    }
```

I create this variable in my module

```
$label = ModVeckomatsedelHelper::renderTranslatableHeader($params, $params->get('field'));
```

if I then echo $label it echoes the label of the first field in the table.

How can I pass the field name as an argument?

My guess was echo $label->my_field but that's not correct.

Comment: Couldn't find info about Component Creator, but took a look in another module and realized that this works:
echo JText::_('MOD_MYMODULE_HEADER_FIELD_MYTABLE_MY_FIELD')

Comment: The module starts by getting all items
`$element = ModMyModuleHelper::getItem($params);`
Printing that array gives both the field label and the field value,
but `print_r ($element->my_field)` will only print the field value.

Comment: Can you show us the print_r of `$element` or the `getItem($params)` source code?

Comment: `print_r ($element)` gives me:
`stdClass Object ( [id] => 15 [asset_id] => 153 [ordering] => 12 [state] => 1 [checked_out] => 0 [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [created_by] => 36 [mon_lunch] => Good meal)`

Comment: And the function: `public static function getItem(&$params)
 {
  $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $vecka = date(W);

  /* @var $params Joomla\Registry\Registry 
  
  $query
   ->select('*')
   ->from($params->get('item_table'))
   ->where('vecka = ' . intval($vecka));

  $db->setQuery($query);
  $element = $db->loadObject();

  return $element;
 }`

Comment: Thanks for asking @NicolaCiciliot, now I can see that `print_r ($element)` does actually not give me the label, it was only me converting the field name to the field label in my mind.

Comment: Added more information to my question. There is actually a function to echo labels, I just haven't been able to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **renderTranslatableHeaderfunction** returns a string based on JText (multilanguage purpose).
If I've understood correctly your question, just add the field name to the function's second parameter and it will give you back the translated label from language file.

```
$label_to_print = ModVeckomatsedelHelper::renderTranslatableHeader($params,"fieldname");
```

Comment: That works great. I can understand that you're not sure if you understood my question, I believe I get variables and functions a bit mixed up.